# IndexError; list index out of range. List has items, and 0 is out of range

Tags: python

This simple code is just compiling a dictionary of numbers. The while loop is throwing an error that 'j' is not in range of 'rankedlen', when 'j' is assigned 0 to start. Whats the issue?

```
result = {}
rankedlen = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,5,5,5]
v = 0
k = 1
j = 0
while j <= len(rankedlen):
    if rankedlen[j] == k:
        v += 1
        j += 1
    else:
        result[k] = v
        k += 1
        v = 0
```

Comment: You would need to change your <= to < in the while statement. len(rankedlen) would return 10, so the while loop would execute with j = 10 thus throwing an out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

The '<=' operator includes 'j'= len(rankedlen). This means at the end of the list, 'j' is out of range. Keep in mind that the length of a list may be 'x', but the last index of that same list is 'x-1'.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some prints to your code:

```
print(len(rankedlen))
while j <= len(rankedlen):
    print(' j ',j,' v ',v,' k ',k)
```

produces:

```
1907:~/mypy$ python3 stack64148094.py 
10
 j  0  v  0  k  1
 j  1  v  1  k  1
 j  2  v  2  k  1
 j  3  v  3  k  1
 j  4  v  4  k  1
 j  4  v  0  k  2
 j  5  v  1  k  2
 j  6  v  2  k  2
 j  7  v  3  k  2
 j  7  v  0  k  3
 j  7  v  0  k  4
 j  7  v  0  k  5
 j  8  v  1  k  5
 j  9  v  2  k  5
 j  10  v  3  k  5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack64148094.py", line 9, in <module>
    if rankedlen[j] == k:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When `j` reaches 10, `rankedlen[10]` produces this error.  Python indexing ranges from 0 to n-1.

changing the while to:

```
while j < len(rankedlen):
```

produces:

```
1909:~/mypy$ python3 stack64148094.py 
10
 j  0  v  0  k  1
 ... 
 j  8  v  1  k  5
 j  9  v  2  k  5
{1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 0, 4: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

> while j <= len(rankedlen):

**change <= to <**